# R leaflet Language of the map : Can we specify to use English language

Tags: r, leaflet

I have just started to use leaflet package with Shiny in R.  For regions like china, in the map the abbreviation is in Chinease language. Can this be changed to English?[image]

I searched for this on the web. But was not able to understand, where and how to search for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see on the map are Tiles, which are plain images generated by the Tile Server you specify (or use by default).

In your case, the Tile Server is OpenStreetMap: you will get the exact same tiles as on openstreetmap.org website (see for example: http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/28.46/86.92)

As these are images, you will understand that you cannot change them.

Now you can change the Tile Server until you find one that serves images with names in the language you need.

Have a look at http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I am able to at least change the map that is in English.

Comment: @KumarManglam how did you changed the language to English ?

Comment: This answer (and question) would benefit from some code...

Answer (score 0):

```
leaflet(Data) %>%
 +     addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite) %>%
```

Like this for example.