# Taking off labels on a leaflet tile layer

Tags: leaflet

I'm wondering if there is a way to take off some of the default labels on a leaflet tile base-map.  For example, I'm using the leaflet "dark matter" tile-set, found here, I believe: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

I'd like to only put on country labels, or city labels, in certain places.  By default, the labels already seem to be set.  Any way to change this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to find a Tile Source with the (only) information you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638103/r-leaflet-language-of-the-map-can-we-specify-to-use-english-language/38640057#38640057