# I should want to traslate mapbox in italian language using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Good day.

I've integrate in my web application Mapbox map using Leaflet javascript library.
In L.tileLayer I have setted as id mapbox/streets-v11.
This is the url in L.tileLayer: "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=".
I have mapped the Italy as center of map.
The map is in english language and I should want to translate it in italian.
It's possibile?
And if yes, how can I do to make it?

Best regards and good work.

Stefano Errani

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638103/r-leaflet-language-of-the-map-can-we-specify-to-use-english-language/38640057?r=SearchResults#38640057

Comment: Tkanks a lot! including leaflet-providers.js and insert OpenStreetMap as argument of L.tileLayer.provider I've obtained the map in italian language.